# how to replace a substring of a line after multiple keywords/patterns have matched

Tags: awk, sed, wildcards

I need to go through thousands of files and find lines that start with

```
# disabledRule:
```

On these lines I need to look for a series of keywords, namely `fileinto` or `fileinto_copy` followed by `create` and `target`. Examples:

```
{s:4:"type";s:8:"fileinto";s:6:"create";b:0;s:6:"target";s:5:"PATTERN";}
{s:4:"type";s:13:"fileinto_copy";s:6:"create";b:0;s:6:"target";s:5:"PATTERN";}
```

After those keywords I need to modify the PATTERN and replace `.` with `/`.

PATTERN can consist of almost any character e.g.

```
simple.folder.structure
more.complex.[department_1] @employee-XY
```

The parts between the keywords can vary slightly and the whole "keywords+PATTERN" pattern can occur multiple times in one line.

It sounds easy but I couldn't figure out a way to make it work with `sed`/`awk` without writing a big script and take apart the lines. I think I'm half decent with `sed` to replace stuff and also to find patterns, but I don't know how to limit the replacement to only the PATTERN.

Any suggestions in what I could use to do this, without writing a longer script? Is there maybe a way with `sed` capture groups?

Update:
As some may have figured out, the files need to be modified because of a migration. We knew that the new software is not fully compatible but as it turns out the above mentioned lines "# disabledRule" are not recognised by the new software at all, hence rendering the problem unsolvable from this perspective.

Comment: Welcome, could you give a real example of PATTERN? **[edit]** the question, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: There are no other `.` in the key-pairs. It's just the sample, or there could be?

Comment: Looks like php serialised data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can probably use address ranges of `sed`, but you don't tell when a `# disabledRule:` section ends. If it ends at the next empty line, for example, and there are no other dots in the given lines outside the pattern of `filecopy` lines, it's extremely simple:

```
sed '/^# disabledRule:$/,/^$/s_\._/_g'
```

But in this case you probably would not ask. This one does addition filtering for the keywords:

```
sed '/^# disabledRule:$/,/^$/{/"fileinto\(_copy\)*".*"create".*"target"/s_\._/_g;}'
```

If this still doesn't match your requirements, adapt it further or explain more details, at best giving a longer example of the file.